# Asymptotic probability $P(A^2=0)$ for a random matrix over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: probability, matrices, summation, asymptotics, nilpotence

Suppose we choose a random $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb F_2$ by setting each entry of the matrix equal to $0$ with probability $0.5$ and $1$ with probability $0.5$ (this is equivalent to choosing from among the $n\times n$ matrices with equal probability). I am trying to calculate the probability that $A^2=0$ asymptotically for large $n$. I believe that the following is a closed form of this probability:

$$P(A^2=0)=\frac{1}{2^{n^2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-4)...(2^n-2^{2k})}{k!}$$

**QUESTION:** Can anyone help me evaluate the asymptotic behavior of the above expression for large values of $n$?

**NOTE:** Because of the $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, I anticipate that we may have to break it down into even and odd cases that have different asymptotic behaviors. Also, whatever asymptotic expression we come up with might make use of the following constant:
$$\nu=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \bigg(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\bigg)\approx 0.28879...$$
which is the asymptotic probability that a randomly chosen matrix is invertible, for large $n$.

Comment: How did you come up with that expression for $\mathbb P(A^2=0)$? Presumably by computing it for small $n$ and then verifying it by induction?

Comment: @Math1000 No, not induction, actually. I did it by choosing $n$ linearly independent vectors to act as bases for the generalized null space $N^*(A)$ of $A$, using the fact that each basis vector $\vec{w}$ of $N^*(A)$ is either a member of the null space $N(A)$, or its image $A\vec{w}$ is a member of the null space $N(A)$. There’s quite a bit more behind it than that, but I don’t think I can explain it all in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. This is a significant increase in the average level of questions in recent months...

I feel that your formula (if I understand it correctly) does not work; for $n=2$, you obtain $3/2^4$ while the correct solution is $4/2^4=2^{-2}$. More generally $prob(A^n=0)=2^{-n}$ (because one has $n$ independent relations on $F_2$ linking the entries of $A$).

For $n=3$, random tests indicate that $prob(A^2=0)\approx 0.04$, while your formula gives $\approx 0.342$.

When $n$ is large, a generic nilpotent matrix satisfies with a large probability $A^{n-1}\not= 0$. Then $prob(A^2=0)$ is much smaller than $2^{-n}$. Random tests seem to indicate that $prob(A^2=0)\approx 2^{-n^2/2}$.

EDIT 1. I see that the OP does not have the strength to comment on my answer. So I ignore him and continue the job.
The subject is studied in

https://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C22%2C316%2C6976&language=french&go=Chercher

More precisely, a correct formula for the number of matrices s.t. $A^2=0$ is

$(1)$ $a_n=coeff(\dfrac{\Pi_{i\geq 1}(1+u/2^i)}{\Pi_{i\geq 1}(1-u^2/2^i)},u^n)(2-1)...(2^n-1)$.

EDIT 2. Let $\alpha_0=1$ and, if $j\geq 1$, then let $\alpha_j=\Pi_{1\leq i\leq j}(1-2^{-i})$. Note that $\alpha_j\rightarrow \nu\approx 0.28878809508660242126$ and $\alpha_j\in [\nu,1]$. We deduce that

$\textbf{Lemma}$.  For a large enough $n$ and $r\leq n/2$, $\dfrac{\alpha_n}{\alpha_r\alpha_{n-2r}}\in[1,3.5]$.

Another formula for $a_n$ is

$(2)$ $a_n=1+\sum_{r=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}2^{2r(n-r)}\dfrac{\alpha_n}{\alpha_r\alpha_{n-2r}}$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. $a_n\in \Omega(2^{n^2/2})$ and $prob(A^2=0)=\Omega(2^{-n^2/2})$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. According to the Lemma, it suffices to show that $b_n=\sum_{r=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}2^{2r(n-r)}\in \Omega(2^{n^2/2}).$

If $n$ is even, then $b_n\sim 2^{n^2/2}(1+2^{-2}+2^{-2.2^2}+2^{-2.3^2}+\cdots)$, that is, $b_n\sim k_{even}2^{n^2/2}$, where

$k_{even}\approx 1.2539100649300971568$.

In the same way, when $n$ is odd, we obtain $b_n\sim k_{odd}2^{n^2/2}$, where $k_{odd}\approx 0.751473630649698988$. $\square$

$\textbf{Remark}$. Experimentally, we see that

$ 2^{-n^2/2}\leq prob(A^2=0)\leq 2\times 2^{-n^2/2}$.

More precisely, calculations seem to show

$\textbf{Conjecture}$. $a_n\sim \tau .2^{n^2/2}$, where

if $n$ is even, then $\tau\approx 1.6793780841750303241$

if $n$ is odd, then $\tau\approx 1.5494800120725299756$.

Comment: It seems the asymptotics is [$n^2/2^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18636/number-of-invertible-0-1-real-matrices) but there they cite [A046747](http://oeis.org/A046747) while you cite [A053722](https://oeis.org/A053722) but the problem seems to be the same and I'm unable to understand why the difference

Comment: @dandide we are on $F_2$ and not over the integers. On the other hand, I wrote some proofs that are mine. Read them.

Comment: I tried but as you can see I was confused by a even a simpler fact, sorry about that and thanks